# В списке содержится несколько нулей. Разместить их вначале списка

Tags: c++, list, односвязный-список

Помогите написать реализацию чтобы нулевые элементы выводились в начале списка, не могу понять.

Ниже представлен код.

Заранее спасибо.

#include

using namespace std;

struct Node // Узел
{

```
int value; // Значение узла (значение)
Node* next; // Следующий элемент узла
```

};

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

```
Node* head = NULL; // голова списка
Node* tail = NULL; // последний элемент списка

int currentValue; // текущее значение
Node* newNode = 0; // текущий узел

int N;
cout << "Введите кол-во чисел в списке: ";
cin >> N;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cout << "Введите число: ";
    cin >> currentValue;

    newNode = new Node();
    newNode->value = currentValue;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}
Node* current = head;  //Указатель на первый элемент списка (на голову)

cout << "\nСписок до изменений: \n";
while (current != NULL) {
    cout << current->value << " ";
    current = current->next;
}
cout << endl;

current = head;

Node* next = NULL;  // Следующий элемент списка
Node* beginZero = NULL;

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        next = current->next;
    {
        if (currentValue == 0) beginZero = current;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        next = current->next;
   {
        if (currentValue == !0) beginZero = current;

   }

current = next;
current = head;

cout << "\nСписок после изменений: \n";
while (current != NULL) {
    cout << current->value << " ";
    current = current->next;
}
cout << endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Или при вводе добавляете нули в начало списка сразу:

```
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else if (currentValue == 0) {
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = newNode ;
        tail = newNode;
    }
```

Если нужно все таки после заполнения, то можно так:

```
cout << "\nСписок до изменений: \n";
while (current != nullptr) {
    cout << current->value << " ";
    current = current->next;
}
cout << endl;

current = head;
if(current != nullptr)
    while (current->next != nullptr)
    {
        auto next = current->next;
        if (next->value == 0) {
            current->next = next->next;
            next->next = head;
            head = next;
        } else {
            current = next;
        }
    }

current = head;

cout << "\nСписок после изменений: \n";
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)))))